# How to create a puffy looking mesh?

Tags: mesh, workflow

I want to create a mesh that looks like this sheep:

[image]

How could I go about achieving a look like this(I'm talking specifically about the puffy body of the sheep)? I tried using multiple spheres together and using a single sphere and sculpting it with the blob brush, but neither really got the look I wanted. I want it to look cartoon like in the picture, so I don't need realistic fur or anything like that. Any tips?

My blob brush monstrosity:

[image]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try using a [displace modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/deform/displace.html) with a [procedural texture](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/blender_render/textures/types/procedural/voronoi.html):

1. Add a cube (<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>)
2. Add a subsurf modifier (<kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>5</kbd>) (where <kbd>5</kbd> refers to the number of viewport subdivisions.)
3. Add a displace modifier, and click *New texture*:

   [image]

   Then click the *properties* icon on the far right of the button to go to the texture settings for the new texture.
4. Set the *type* to *Voronoi*:

   [image]

   I found that using *Distance squared* gives more rounded looking puffs, which might be what you want.
5. Back in the modifiers panel, reduce the strength of the displace modifier to some negative value so that the puffs are convex instead of concave.

   [image]
6. Optionally model the cube into a shape approximately how you want the wool to be, and add a second displace modifier for larger displacements (you can use *object* coordinates and a scaled empty to make the texture larger):

   [image]

## Result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hahaha a Suzanne sheep, lovely.

Comment: Holy crap, some time between ~2.47 and now displacement became _amazing_.

Comment: @gandalf3 what was your render settings for the lighting and cell shading? would you mind adding that as a *bonus* update step to your answer?

Comment: @mushcraft Uploaded the .blend. Merry christmas :)

Answer (score 4):

You could start with an scaled UV sphere and a cylinder (removed the top part):

[image]

Dup the cylinder and rotate both parts at the eyes position:

[image]

Use a *Boolean modifier* to intersect the UV-sphere with the cylinders.

[image]

Add an *Edge Split* modifier to improve the contours of the eyes.

Duplicate the shape and delete the faces (mesh) from the face (shape) area.

In *Sculpt Mode* use the *Blob* brush:

[image]

After that you could add details and adjust the fur.

#### Result (with dyntopo enabled while sculpting):

[image]