# Is it possible to add Noise to a Geometry?

Tags: modeling

i'm modeling a 3D rabbit...does Blender have a option to add 'noise' to the geometry? like a sphere or a cube? i need it to do the tail, that looks like a cotton ball or something like that.

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19690/how-to-create-a-puffy-looking-mesh

Comment: @beavoru rabbit tails are exactly like the sheep in the question that cegaton posted. just... browner.