# How to make clouds

Tags: modeling, workflow

So I saw this pic of clouds in game The Witness and I really liked how they made the clouds. How to reproduce them?

[image: example reference clouds]

Comment: Those were painted, probably a texture on some planes

Comment: oh..well that's a shame

Comment: ^^ the novice is right... If you download a cloud texture, set it's type to "Billboard" and make it shadeless, gigantic, and always slowly wheeling across the sky, you should be good.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19690/how-to-create-a-puffy-looking-mesh

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6835/599

Answer (score 4):

sorry for the previous short and unexplained answer :)

First open up blender and add a plane, then UV unwrap it like below
(I've made a very simple cloud texture for that with transparency)

[image]

then add a plane so we can actually see something in the test render

[image]

then go to rendered shading mode by enabling it from the red  icon indicator

[image]

notice how the transparency (alpha channel) has been filled with black?

its because of the default material setup as shown in the picture below!
the diffuse shader can't render transparency

[image]

its only using a diffuse shader with a image with transparency

now, if we add a transparent shader with mix shader node and the alpha from original image as the fac value then we will get something like below

[image]

**its basically checking weather a part of the texture is transparent and if so it is feeding it through the transparent shader so we can get the actual transparency**.....
and the rest is going through the diffuse shader

by this method you can get the cloud you were referring to.....

now, you might wanna import image as a plane (check if the addon is enabled) then apply this method, but for some wired reason (I don't know why) its not working in my blender 2.74...
hope somebody can lighten me up :)

Comment: This is visible form one side only? Because in the Witness the cloud is 3d...meaning that every side looks different and like a real cloud, random.

Comment: @SamuraiFox , yes one side only....
if want to get something more like real clouds then I suggest making a sphere more like a cloud (maybe with sculpting mode?) and then use Volume Scatter as the material and set the color to white...

maybe add a texture to randomize it :)

Comment: that sounds promising...I'll try that